# JSONObject accumulate and put converting this "[]" string to array

Tags: java, arrays, json

Have a look at the below code snippet.

value of the key 'sample' is string `"[]"`

Both `put` & `accumulate` functions are converting it into empty array `[]`.

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject();
        resObj.put("sample","[]");
        System.out.println(resObj);

    }
}
```

**output:**

```
{"sample":[]}
```

I want the value as it ("[]").
like:

```
{"sample":"[]"}
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Update:**

Above example is just to explain the problem.

In actual from a big XML I am generating a JSON.
In the generated JSON there is no issue.

While passing the entire JSON string to accumulate & put functions facing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried escaping square brackets ?

Comment: Why do you want `[]` to be surrounded by double-quotes? From the output, it seems  logical that JSONObject would consider `"[]"` as an empty list as lists are a part of the JSON format. Have you tried using escaping via `\\`?

Comment: Try using `resObj.put("sample","\"[]\"");` That'd work.

Comment: @procrastinator I can do this as from an XML I am generating a JSON. updated the question. please have a look

Comment: @ShreyanshGandhi Have one field called range. if some value is present it will be like "[1 - 20]" otherwise it will be "[]". That's the requirement can change anything in this.

Comment: That makes me unlcear `While passing the entire JSON string to accumulate & put functions facing this issue.` What does the JSON data contain here?

Comment: @DixitSingla I believe `JSONObject` is not the correct type to use here. Why not create a POJO or `Map<String,Object>`that serves your purpose (containing a field `sample` of type `String`)? When you JSONize this POJO using libraries such as `Gson`, you should get the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `json-lib` library you are using is a rather old implementation, try the "official" org.json one which can be found [here](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) and using maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

Then

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
System.out.println( new JSONObject().put("sample","[]"));
```

will correctly output

```
{"sample":"[]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can ude [Google json library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1)

it works for me and the output is`{"sample":"[]"}`